# When I click the button more than once, array gets a value. I want it to take all values in the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a listAPI value where I get the information from the API. Its output is as follows.

```
//output - console.log(listAPI)

5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "1", name: "name 1", active: "true"}
1: {id: "2", name: "name 2", active: "false"}
2: {id: "3", name: "name 3", active: "false"}
3: {id: "4", name: "name 4", active: "true"}
4: {id: "5", name: "name 5", active: "true"}
```

When I click on the Select button, I want to map this data to the firstList for the active values and the false ones to the secondList.

Then I open a modal and show the firstList and secondList values in the input section.

```
const selectAll = () => {
        console.log(listAPI)
        listAPI.map((data) => {
            console.log(data) 
            if (data.active === false) {
                console.log(data.name)
                setFirstList([...firstList,data.id])
            }
            else {
                setSecondList([...secondList, data.id])
            }
        })
        console.log(firstList)
        console.log(secondList)
     }
```

The firstList and secondList values do not fill when the code runs. How can I fix this? I could not understand why it is not working. It just doesn't add values to lists. It only starts adding the last value when I click the select button more than once.

Comment: Where is your HTML or modal JS code?

Comment: what is your setFirstList() and setSecondList()  function?

Comment: const [firstList, setFirstList] = useState([]);     const [secondList, setSecondList] = useState([]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State update is not synchronous. Try using this:

```
listAPI.forEach((data) => {
   if (data.active === "false") {
       setFirstList((prevFirstList) => [...prevFirstList, data.id]);
    else {
        setSecondList((prevSecondList) => [...prevSecondList, data.id]);
    }
});
```

Edit: updated comparison according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67126603/2333214

Long version:

```
listAPI.forEach((data) => {
      if (data.active === "false") {
        setFirstList((prevFirstList) => {
          const newFirstList = [...prevFirstList, data.id];
          console.log(newFirstList);
          return newFirstList;
        });
        else {
          setSecondList((prevSecondList) => {
            const newSecondList = [...prevSecondList, data.id];
            console.log(newSecondList);
            return newSecondList;
          });
        }
      });
```

Comment: This will still fail, you are comparing types in the first IF statement while they share two different types. changing === to == should fix it.

Comment: @Unkwn they are both strings? Maybe I missed something

Comment: Oh no need to worry, you've edited the post and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

cause in your code :

```
if (data.active === false)
```

You compare `data.active` which is a `string` with `false`, which is a `boolean`

Answer (score 0):

You could check the `activate` state of each object and map it to a result using a reducer function.

```js
const key = isActive === 'true' ? 'active' : 'inactive'
```

```js
const listApi = [
  { id: "1", name: "name 1", active: "true"  },
  { id: "2", name: "name 2", active: "false" },
  { id: "3", name: "name 3", active: "false" },
  { id: "4", name: "name 4", active: "true"  },
  { id: "5", name: "name 5", active: "true"  },
];

const result = listApi.reduce((acc, { active: isActive, ...rest }) =>
  ((key => ({ ...acc, [key]: [...acc[key], { ...rest }] }))
(isActive === 'true' ? 'active' : 'inactive')), { active: [], inactive: [] });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```